# Setup home network with two routers and ZeroTier

Tags: home-networking

I need some advice about my network setup.

Before I had the following setup for my home network:

[image]

- Router A: In Bridge Mode
- Router B: 192.168.1.1 and DHCP with 192.168.1.0/24
- Access Point A: 192.168.1.X
- Devices: 192.168.1.X

After we changed our ISP and got a new router from them, it was not possible anymore to put the ISP router into the bridge mode.

I have configured all my fix IP's on the Router B and because I just needed to switch my ISP router, everything is still working - except the remote access to my raspberry pi, because the new ISP does not provide a public IPv4 address. Sure i could use IPv6, but not on my mobile phone.

So, now I want to setup my new home network like this:

- Router A: 192.168.2.1 and DHCP with 192.168.2.0/24
- Router B: 192.168.1.1 and DHCP with 192.168.1.0/24
- Access Point A: 192.168.1.X
- Devices: 192.168.1.X

No device except Router B is connected to the Router A.

I do not want to change the Router B to the connection mode as client, because this will shut down the firewall. This, because maybe I will change the ISP again and can again use the bridge mode. Another reasen is, i thinking about to pay for an fixed ipv4 address and put the Router B into the DMZ of Router A and then it should work as before.

So because I want to access some devices in my home network from my smartphone, I thinking about to setup ZeroTier to reach this goal. As fas as I understand, I can bypass the problem of not having an public ipv4 address, because the route will be open.
Also I want to install pihole on the raspberry pi (192.168.1.3) and use the DNS within the 192.168.1.0/24 network to block ads for every device.

Does this setup work as expected or did I miss something?

Current setting of FritzBox
[image]